# Rglpk install error on google compute engine

Tags: r, google-compute-engine, rstudio-server

I am running rstudio on a n1-highmem-2 VM through google compute engine. I am trying to install Rglpk on it but I keep getting this error

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-08-
18/src/contrib/Rglpk_0.6-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 20892 bytes (20 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 20 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Rglpk’ ...
** package ‘Rglpk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: GLPK: No such file or directory
Makevars:10: recipe for target 'GLPK.ts' failed
make: *** [GLPK.ts] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rglpk’ 
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rglpk’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘Rglpk’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have GLPK installed, but it is not finding the directory. How do I modify the Rglpk package so that it finds the GLPK directory?